# How do I count from 1 to 10 with the line removed when it ends? ( python )

Tags: python

**How do I count from 1 to 10 with the line removed when it ends??**
*on python*

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**try that:**

```
for i in range(11):
print(f'\r{i}', end='')
```

**To see the result slowly:**

```
import time

for i in range(11):
    print(f'\r{i}', end='')
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: it's working > thanks

Answer (score 1):

@Hassan's code works, and the explanation is because when you print out a string to the console, it doesn't flush itself unless you print a newline "`\n`", and because the `print()` function appends by default "`\n`" to every string, it flushes itself every time by default. To avoid that you need to add a keyword argument `end=""` to `print()` so it won't flush and you can print again to the same line using the `\r` character at the beginning, which lets you override what is written in that line.

Comment: thank you ......